# System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, web-services, remote-access

I'm creating a webservice ( in .NET 3.5) to obtain SSL certificate information of a remote server based on the domain name and i have a client which is a console application to call the service. presently for me there are 11 domain names. i am able to obtain the SSL information for all server except one.

my code is:

```
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {            
        client.Connect(strDNSEntry, 443);

        SslStream ssl = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        try
        {
            ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(strDNSEntry);    //Error thrown here
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            log.Debug(e.Message);
            ssl.Close();
            client.Close();
            return cert;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Debug(e.Message);
            ssl.Close();
            client.Close();
            return cert;
        }
        cert = new X509Certificate2(ssl.RemoteCertificate);
        ssl.Close();
        client.Close();
        return cert;
    }
```

the error is

> *"[System.IO.IOException] = {"Authentication failed because the remote
>   party has closed the transport stream."}".*

When I examined during debugging at SSLStream I found the error as "

> *This operation is only allowed using a successfully authenticated
>   context".*

Is that because I don't have enough credentials is it throwing the error or any issues with the service? Also I tried to do Remote desktop conncetion to that server, I'm unable to coonect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use "Windows Communication Foundation" WCF framework, and create a Service Class, then configure Client/Server TCP bindings parameters correctly with SSL transport configuration.

If you try to do this, I will give you a test case later.